# AWS Beanstalk keep launching EC2 instances in same AZ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've configured my Beanstalk environment in high-availability fashion by specifying:

- minimum = 2 instances
- maximum = 4 instances

in 2 Availability Zones and specified (ap-southeast-2a & ap-southeast-2b).
Cross Availability Zones Load Balancing is also enabled.
I also selected the Subnets of the EC2 instances to be in 2 Availability Zones.

However,
When Beanstalk setup and configure the environment, it keeps launching EC2 instances in the same Availability Zone (ap-southeast-2a)!!
How can I tell Beanstalk to launch EC2 instances in 2 separate AZs? it seems to me that Beanstalk should respect the fact that I have selected 2 AZ and a minimum of 2 EC2 instances so that it should launch 1 EC2 instance in each AZ as I have selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue.
I ended terminating the environment and re-creating it.

I don't know what's going on with the Beanstalk 'create environment' wizard but it seems not to handle changes in configuration before save very well.

My Advice to anyone using the Beanstalk 'create environment' wizard is not to make any modification to any value once you select it. The wizard does not seem to handle some of these values modification well (it may show that the value has changed to newly selected value but behind the scene it is not applying the new value so when you create the environment you may find some un-expected configuration taking place).

After terminating and re-creating the environment, I can see 2 EC2 instances created in each AZ.